# How to move pseudo-element under its parent block?

Tags: css

I want the green element to be under the text box and also under image.
I tried to set the z-index for each element, but nothing has changed.
Can I reach this through the z-index property?

I can't change html. And I also want the pseudo-element to be a child of the text block for the adaptive height

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
}

.col1 {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.col2 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.col2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: -60px;
  width: 150px;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: seagreen;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="col1">
    <img class="image" src="http://satyr.io/200x150/1" />
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima esse ipsam error repudiandae ut amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The green element already is under the text and the image. What's the problem?

Comment: Declaring a `z-index` on `.col2` will actually attribute a higher stacking context to the absolutely positioned `pseudo-element` since it is nested within `.col2` (even though it has been given a negative value `z-index`) - if it wasn't (nested within `.col2`) just declaring a higher `z-index` on `.col2` would have worked as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `z-index: 1` from class `.col2`. So, the green block will appear under the image as well as the text box.

Comment: In my case, this solution will work.  
But if the element `.item` has a background, then the _pseudo_ element would not be visible.

Answer (score 2):

You could place an element inside `<div class="col2">` because the pseudo element cannot have a lower z-index that the element itself. And then place an div inside of `<div class="col2">` which you could apply the z-index and the gray background on.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot change html. I wrote about it in my question
Any case thanks for that:
> because the pseudo element cannot have a lower z-index that the element itself.

Comment: I'm sorry I overlooked that detail.. Glad you found an answer.